# Next not looping in vb.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, function

I have create a function:

```
Public Shared Function appid()
        Dim appidQ = From v In db_apps.app_users
                     Where v.NT_id = System.Environment.UserName
                     Select v
        For Each v In appidQ
            Return Convert.ToInt32(v.app_id)
        Next v
        Return appid()
    End Function
```

I am trying to return EVERY app_id for a user a place it in a viewdata (just for testing I will eventually be placing this info in a cookie.)  Now this should be returning 2 records, as I currently have 2 records that meet the criteria of the query specified in appidQ.  Upon debugging appidQ is indeed returning both records.  However when I step into a little further the "For Each" doesn't loop so although appidQ is returning 2 records the function is only returning the first record. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Obviously the Return appid() cause it to exit the loop here is my new code:

```
Public Shared Function appid()
    Dim appidQ = From v In db_apps.app_users
                 Where v.NT_id = System.Environment.UserName
                 Select v
    For Each v In appidQ
        Dim var = v.app_id
    Next v
    Return appid()
End Function
```

But it still doesn't do what I need it to.  I need it to return the results of

```
For Each v In appidQ
  Dim var = v.app_id
Next v
```

Comment: What data type is app_id?

Comment: @Douglas Barbin in my database it's an tinyint, but Entity Framework pulls it in as a byte.

Comment: Can you give us a minimal code snippet of how you are using the result of the function? It will give us some context.

Comment: As the keyword itself implies, "Return" will return value back to the stack thereby exiting the loop or function and 'returning' the value to whatever called it

Comment: firstly `Dim var=v.app_id` within the loop will be redeclared everytime you loop,and it cant be accessed outside the loop. declare a String or sumtn outside the loop and concatenate the results followed by a newline character everytime you loop

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am trying to return it within the index with: ViewData("Test") = appid().

Comment: I see you are happy with Chris's answer, but is there a reason you use `...Select v` instead of `...Select v.app_id`? The latter is more direct at getting the item you want.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I like Chris's answer because it works, if you have a more efficient suggestion please feel free to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already noticed the `return` statement should be moved after the loop to get all the results.

```
Public Shared Function appid() As List(Of Int32)
    Dim appidQ = From v In db_apps.app_users
                 Where v.NT_id = System.Environment.UserName
                 Select v
    Dim result As New List(Of Int32)
    For Each v In appidQ
        result.Add(Convert.ToInt32(v.app_id))
    Next v
    Return result
End Function
```

EDIT

It seems from your comment that what you need is a String representation of the list. And when you try the `ToString()` extension, it returns the name of the object (ex: `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]` So I don't know if there is a more efficient way, but this should work:

```
Public Shared Function appid() As String
    Dim appidQ = From v In db_apps.app_users
                 Where v.NT_id = System.Environment.UserName
                 Select v

    'Create a String representation
    Dim stringList As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    For Each v In appidQ
        stringList.Append(v.app_id.ToString())

        'Separator
        If Not counter = appidQ.Count - 1 Then
            stringList.Append("; ")
        End If
        counter += 1
    Next
    Return stringList.ToString
End Function
```

Comment: This returns: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32] it should return 1 and 2. How I'm calling it could also be the issue: ViewData("foo") = appid()

Comment: @aaronmallen of course `appid()` returns a `List<int>`...containing 1 and 2. You've got to loop on your `ViewData("foo")` to get your 1 and 2.

Comment: @aaronmallen What type is `ViewData("foo")`?

Comment: @Chris this one looks promising, I will let you know how this one works out tomorrow when I get back to work. To answer your question ViewData("foo") is called in the controller like this: ViewData("foo") = appid()

Comment: @Chris This still returns: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' when I call ViewData("foo") = appid().  I need it to return the results in a string or something to that effect.

Comment: @chris no dice: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'CC_Metrics_Apps.app_users ElementAtOrDefault[app_users](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[CC_Metrics_Apps.app_users], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @aaronmallen Maybe this?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `Return` statement in your loop.

`Return` is at the function level, so your loop (and function) will be exited after first passage in the loop.

You should do somtething like that (I'm not a VB guy).

```
Public Shared Function appid()
        Return (From v In db_apps.app_users
                     Where v.NT_id = System.Environment.UserName
                     Select v).ToList()
            .Select(Function(p)  Convert.ToInt32(p.app_id)).ToList()

    End Function
```

Then in your view, if you're using a ViewData, something like that.

```
For Each id As Int32 In CType(ViewData("foo"), List(Of Int32)
...
Next
```

Comment: This returns the query not the query results.

Comment: @aaronmallen you mean it returns an IEnumerable or an IQueryable, but not a list of int ? Then try to add a ToList()

Comment: So now its giving me a INT32 to byte conversion error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(Byte)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @aaronmallen if it returns an IEnumerable or IQueryable, it just means that the query is deferred and will execute whenever you need to actually iterate through the results.  .ToList() will execute the query immediately.

Comment: @aaronmallen so you've got to enumerate first. See my edit maybe

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus The lambda you added at the end is doing the exact same Select and Convert that the query expression before it is doing, and I think the compiler will know this and ignore it.  I think the issue here is actually that app_id is not a type that can be converted to Integer.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I disagree. Linq to Entities doesn't know how to manage Convert.ToInt32. But Linq to objects does. So you have to enumerate first before Converting.

Comment: It wont even take the line : .Select(Function(p)  Convert.ToInt32(v.app_id)).ToList()

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus You're right about LINQ to Entities not knowing how to manage the conversion.  My mistake on that one.

Comment: @aaronmallen See my edited answer.  Raphael's answer was very close; it was just selecting the wrong variable.  By the time the 2nd select is done, the variable v is already out of scope.

Comment: @aaronmallen typo: wrote v.app_id instead of p.app_id. Edited

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus this throws an error in syntax it says: "Leading ".", "!" may only happen in a with statement"

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, you `Return`, so you exit the function altogether (and the loop in particular).

If you do not `Return`, you will not exit the function, so you will have a chance to continue looping.

Answer (score 0):

You REALLY should have Option Strict On.  Since we have no idea what the data type of app_id is, and you have Option Strict Off, we can't tell what exactly we are supposed to be returning.

Try this:

```
Public Shared Function appid()
    Return (From v In db_apps.app_users
                 Where v.NT_id = System.Environment.UserName
                 Select v.app_id).ToList()
End Function
```

It would be better if it were strongly-typed, but this should give you the result you want.

EDIT:  If you need to convert to Int32, try this:

```
Public Shared Function appid()
    Return (From v In db_apps.app_users
                 Where v.NT_id = System.Environment.UserName
                 Select v).ToList()
        .Select(Function(p)  Convert.ToInt32(p.app_id)).ToList()

End Function
```